# Can a poorly done second degree ruin one's academic record?

Tags: grades, second-degree, curriculum

Currently I have a BSc degree in Computer Science, and in the future I plan to get a Master degree in Computer Science. In my opinion, my BSc grades are good enough to help me be accepted at good universities in my country.

Also I'm considering doing a second BSc degree (in Electrical or Mechatronics Engineering), but I don't think I'll have enough time to study in order to get very good grades.

Could this ruin my academic record? Would it lower my chances of being accepted in a Master's course in the area of Computer Science?

Comment: What are graduation grades? Do you mean the grades you received for your BSc?

What is a graduation course?

Comment: Regardless of my above questions, I don't see how another course can "ruin [your] academic record." If your results are bad, then you can always omit them.

Comment: Exactly. By graduation course I mean the course you take to get a BSc degree.

Comment: @user2768 Indeed. But would it be more beneficial if you didn't omit the fact that you've taken a second BSc degree, despite the not so good grades? I don't know if the fact that you've managed to complete another BSc course would compensate for the medium grades.

Comment: I've attempted to improve the question based upon these comments. Hopefully, they'll be visible after peer review.

Comment: A second degree will take a lot of time, so it seems unlikely that you'll complete it prior to enrolling on your Master's course. Thus, I don't see how it will impact your chances of getting a place on a Master's course. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @user2768 I wouldn't be able to do both at the same time. I would have to finish the second BSc first.

Comment: I suggest that you enrol on the Master's course, that qualification appears to be your goal. In parallel, you can study a second BSc part-time; perhaps you drop the second BSc, perhaps you eventually finish it. One question you should ask yourself: why do you want the second BSc?

Comment: See also some of the related questions (in the bar to the right). Link any truly related questions here, so that they can be used by others in the future.

Comment: @user2768 Thank you for your advice. I didn't find any _truly_ related question here.

Comment: There seems to be little point in taking the second BSc if you don't expect to study enough to get at least acceptable grades. Engineering courses tend to be cumulative - you will be lost in later courses if you have not fully absorbed earlier material.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I just fear that the lack of time won't allow me to study hard enough to keep up with the grades I had in my first degree, thus lowering my "average" grades (considering both degrees) together with the chances to be accepted in a Master's program. I'm aware that an engineering course demands a lot of effort, which I'm willing to undertake, but I'm also aware that it will be a lot harder than the first time, because back then I was full-time dedicated to the graduation.

Comment: @user2768 - RE: _If your results are bad, then you can always omit them_. Not necessarily so. Many graduate schools want to see ALL transcripts as part of the admissions process, and clearly state so. If the O.P. got a second degree from the same institution, it might be impossible to get a transcript with just the good grades and not the bad ones. If the second degree was from a different institution, that would be easier to omit, but it's still a risk – a violation that could result in a revoked admission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

I think it is pretty obvious that **if you provide the transcript for your second degree, a poor performance harms your chances**.  This provides relevant information about your academic ability and/or work ethic, which a graduate program would consider.  It might even be weighed more heavily than your first degree, since it is more recent (and in a relevant subject to your planned masters').

So the question becomes **can you just not tell graduate programs about your second degree?**  I don't think this is a viable option.  A graduate program will expect you to submit information about all previous studies.  Not submitting a transcript for a second batchelor's degree will most likely be breaking their rules.  You would likely have to be deceptive in any application, interviews, and discussions with the potential graduate institution.  I think this is just wrong, but even if you don't have any moral qualms about it, you are placing yourself in a very bad position.  There is a chance you could get away with it, but you also might get caught, and that would have serious consequences.

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely take this into account in my decision. Probably I should postpone the second BSc to a moment after getting the Master's, if I decide to take the BSc at all.